# Different limits convergence L2 and a.s.

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, limits, measure-theory, functions

If a sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n \geq 0}$ which are defined in some probability space converges to a limit $f$ almost surely and to a limit $f^{\prime}$ in $L_2$-norm, then is necessarily $f = f^{\prime}$?

Comment: Both $L^p$-convergence and a.s.-convergence imply convergence in probability, thus the limts coincide a.s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $L^2$-convergence implies convergence in probiability. Hence $f_n \to f'$ in probiability. Convergence in probiability implies the existence of a subsequence converging almost surely, that is $f_{n_k} \to f'$ almost surely. As also $f_{n_k} \to f$ almost surely, we have $f = f'$ almost surely.